# Tutorial CGRectMake Understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, gesture, cgrectmake

I am following a tutorial and I am a bit confused on this line of code...

```
sideView.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ? -swipedCell.frame.size.width : swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
```

What does `gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ? -swipedCell.frame.size.width :` mean?

I have never seen it in my experience. What does the `==` and `? -` and `:` mean in this statement? Or could you explain the whole thing? What would this make the frame if I swiped left, and right?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matthias, but I am not just asking about that, I want to know the direction that it is and what the line means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a short form if statement and could be written:

```
if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    sideView.frame = CGRectMake(-swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
} else {
    sideView.frame = CGRectMake(swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
}
```

`==` is just the standard equivalence check. `?` is the start of a short form if operator and is completed by the `:`.

---

As rmaddy pointed out, the above isn't strictly what's going on, it's more like:

```
CGFloat x;

if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    x = -swipedCell.frame.size.width;
} else {
    x = swipedCell.frame.size.width;
}

sideView.frame = CGRectMake(x, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: This is not a good example since the ternary operator is only used for one value within `CGRectMake`. So your code if not really a suitable representation of what is going on.

Comment: @rmaddy, true, added a bit which is more representative, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Question mark (?) in the condition is called a ternery operator.

Before ? operator, the statement shows condition. After ? operator, first choice says the fulfilment of condition and the second shows violence of condition. So, basically it is short form of if-else.

```
if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
    sideView.frame = CGRectMake(-swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
    sideView.frame = CGRectMake(swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.frame.size.width, swipedCell.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: actually it's called **Ternary** ;-)

Comment: @Apurv Ternary, not ternery.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Actually, it's called the **conditional operator.** "ternary" is just the property that it has 3 operands. Other operators could have 3 operands too.

Answer (score -3):

CGRectMake's signature is CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

In this case the sideView would move to left and be hidden if you swipe in the right direction which is achieved by giving a negative x value.

Comment: >>What would this make the frame if I swiped left, and right?
That's what I was trying to explain. How is that wrong answer ? Please explain.